# Вывод из процедуры результатов через OUT параметр

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Необходимо реализовать вывод из процедуры через параметр OUT не используя буфера обмена, то есть `dbms_output.put_line`.

Процедура находится в пакете.

```
PROCEDURE array_app
    (street IN Streets.TITLE%TYPE,
    dom IN APARTMENTS.HOUSE%TYPE,
    res OUT Varchar2) 
IS
    CURSOR my_cur IS SELECT DISTINCT idapart FROM POSSESSION;
    CURSOR cur1 (street IN VARCHAR2, dom IN INTEGER)  
    IS
        SELECT APARTMENTS.id, num FROM APARTMENTS, Streets
        WHERE HOUSE = dom AND TITLE = street AND APARTMENTS.IDSTREET = Streets.ID;
    kv INTEGER;
    cnumber number;
    str Varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    res := '';
    OPEN cur1 (street, dom);
    FETCH cur1 INTO cnumber, kv;
        FOR f IN  my_cur  LOOP
            IF f.idapart = cnumber THEN
                str := res;
                select str || ', ' || kv INTO res from dual;
                RETURN;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

И вызов процедуры

```
DECLARE
   res1 Varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   pack.array_app('Татищева', 75, res1);
END;
```

Пример данных:
Это таблица помещений, где соответственно столбцы код, улица и номер дома и номер квартиры:

```
CREATE TABLE Apartments (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, idstreet VARCHAR2(100), house INTEGER NOT NULL, num INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Apartments (id, idstreet, house, num) VALUES (1, 'Татищева', 75, 5);
INSERT INTO Apartments (id, idstreet, house, num) VALUES (2, 'Кирова', 3, 15);
INSERT INTO Apartments (id, idstreet, house, num) VALUES (3, 'Новая', 28, 34);
INSERT INTO Apartments (id, idstreet, house, num) VALUES (4, 'Татищева', 75, 150);
```

Также имеется таблица владения, в которой содержится как раз код объекта владения:

```
CREATE TABLE Possession (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, idapart INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Apartments);

INSERT INTO Possession (id, idapart) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Possession (id, idapart) VALUES (2, 4);
```

Соответственно, в результате выбирается запись с кодом 1 и возвращается номер квартиры. Если в наборе входных данных будет несколько элементов входящих в обе таблицы с данными, то вернуться должны все соответствующие номера квартир.

Comment: А что вы понимаете под _вернуть результат_? Раз процедура работает, то результат она уже вернула. И заодно уточните,  что такое _множество объектов_, которое желательно учесть.

Comment: Результат нужно вернуть в видимой для пользователя форме, например через таблицу dual, как я понимаю. Но как его туда передать не понятно. Множество объектов в данном случае это массив, который может быть либо пуст либо содержать n-ое количество элементов

Comment: Ну так ваш my_cur это в каком то роде массив. Почему вы его не возвращаете?

Comment: Эти два курсора несут в себе массивы значений, которые я сравниваю и если элемент есть и там и там то он попадает в результирующий список иначе пропускается. Поэтому я не могу вернуть на текущий момент эти курсоры

Comment: А зачем вам два курсора? Почему  вы не  перенесёте сравнение в один курсор? Тогда и процедура не нужна, просто  напишите запрос и выполните его.

Comment: По видимому и вас [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/217579). Просто добавте в вопрос (или на [sql-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18)) пример входных данных и опишитет желаемый результат.

Comment: Вообще не очень понимаю, как можно сравнение поместить в курсор в данном случае. Но процедура мне необходима по тз

Comment: Может это всё таки не тз, а учебное задание? Задача пока выглядит так, чтобы вы что-то подучили, а не решили ее быстро и эффективно.  Входные данные еще не полные  их лучше давать в виде create table ...; insert ...

Comment: Осталось только привести ожидаемый результат. Как он должен выгядеть? Что такое - _в видимой для пользователя форме_?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что как строка (хотя можно и другими вариантами) из номеров помещений разделенных любым разделителем, например 4, 53, 90. Видимая форма это любое видимое отображение результата, кроме dbms_output.put_line

Comment: Так всё таки не как множество объектов или массива, так как строка оными не является?

Comment: Я предполагаю что результат должен быть строкой, но принимаются все варианты

Comment: Не в тему, касательно вопроса по динамическому запросу, который вы сегодня удалили: это в задании стоит, что запрос должен быть динамическим? Почему спрашиваю? Просто задача решается довольно просто не динамическим запросом.

Comment: Да, задача именно в динамическом запросе, хотя не динамически я не вижу более рационального способа. Было бы интересно посмотреть на иной вариант решения. И тот человек который задал тот вопрос не я)

Comment: Рациональный способ - написать статический запрос с двумя подстановочными переменными. Вроде очень просто.

Comment: Вот написал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1102483/217579) со статическим вариантом решения.

Comment: Спасибо за наглядное решение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно например вот так:

```sql
create or replace package pack1 as
    procedure array_app (street varchar2, house integer, cur1 out sys_refcursor);
end;
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    procedure array_app (street varchar2, house integer, cur1 out sys_refcursor) is
    begin
        open cur1 for 
            select a.num 
            from apartments a
            where a.house = array_app.house 
            and a.idstreet = array_app.street
            and exists (
                select 1 
                from possession p 
                where p.idapart = a.id
            );
    end array_app;
end pack1;
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```sql
var cur1 refcursor
exec pack1.array_app('Татищева', 75, :cur1)
print cur1

       NUM
----------
       150
         5
```

Comment: В oracle, на сколько я знаю, нет функции print

Comment: есть, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm

Comment: @Александр Ну я же не от руки результат написал. Попробуйте.

Comment: Процедура компилируется, но куда выводится результат не понятно

Comment: @Александр В смысле? А куда вы его обычно выводите?

Comment: Ну если если результат некая выборка то в query result, если использовать dbms, то в её собственное окно. А куда нужно в данном случае? Где ловить результат

Comment: @Александр Какой инструмент вы используете? _то в её собственное окно_ - в чьё её? Просто скопировать и выполнить, разве у вас не получается?

Comment: SqlDeveloper, скопировал, выполнил, запустил получил результат что процедура выполнена и все больше ничего не вывелось

Comment: @Александр Ааа, тогда понятно. У вас курсор ничего не возвращает. Попробуйте только запрос из процедуры выполнить. Проверьте данные, которые вы привели в вопросе и те, которые у вас в таблицах.

Comment: Да я проверил и смог получить результат, но в вашем коде перед exists не хватает not, так как подзапрос не должен возвращать не одной записи

Comment: Главное, что вы розабрались и поняли как это работает. Мой запрос построен на основе кода  и данных приведённых в вашем вопросе. Почему в нём должно быть `not exists` непонятно, т.к. тогда  `IF f.idapart = cnumber THEN` в вашем коде неверно.