# Отсутствие правой скобки в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax

Пишу динамический запрос SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select next_day(to_date(' || god || q'['-01-01' , 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), 'ПНД')
+ (']' || n || '-2)* 7 FROM DUAL' INTO t;
```

Пишет, что отсутствует правая скобка, но вроде все стоят на месте.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может, потому, что у вас нечетное кол-во кавычек?

Answer (score 6):

Скопировав выражение из вопроса в запрос, получил (подсказка на ошибки `---^`):

```
select 
'select next_day(to_date(' || 2020 || q'['-01-01' , 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), 'ПНД') + (']' || 1 || '-2)* 7 FROM DUAL'  expr 
from dual;

EXPR                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select next_day(to_date(2020'-01-01' , 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), 'ПНД') + ('1-2)* 7 FROM DUAL
                     ---^---^                                 ---^
```

Затраченное время без учёта оформления ответа составило где-то 1 мин.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ к [комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094316/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-out-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80?noredirect=1#comment1897439_1094316) :

> задача именно в динамическом запросе, хотя не динамически я не вижу более рационального способа. Было бы интересно посмотреть на иной вариант решения.

Когда есть смысл в динамическом запросе? Только если во время выполнения запроса не известны идентификаторы БД, например: имена таблиц, представлений, столбцов и тд.
Другими словами то, к чему нельзя применить подстановочные переменные.
Во всех остальных случаях следует использовать статические запросы.

Запрос для задачи как в вопросе выглядит очень просто:

```sql
with function nextMonday (yearNo number, weekNo number) return date is
begin 
    return next_day (trunc (to_date (to_char (yearNo), 'yyyy'), 'rr')+(weekNo-1)*7, 'MON');
end;
data (yearNo, weekNo) as (
    select 2020, 13 from dual
)
select nextMonday (yearNo, weekNo) monday from data
/
```

Результат:

```
MONDAY             
-------------------
2020-03-30 00:00:00
```

PS проблематика граничных значений номера недели: 52, 53, или 53, 54 для США, в этом ответе не расматривается.